# How can I disable Ctrl+p in Awesomium?

Tags: c#, awesomium

I'm trying to disable the `ctrl+p` command in a WPF application with Awesomium. When you press `ctrl+p` Awesomium saves a pdf from the document.

I try with JavaScript and c# code but nothing works.

JS (it open the window before the function):

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('body').keydown(function (event) {
        // alert('this');
        if (event.which == 80 && event.ctrlKey) {
            return false;
            //alert('me');   
        }
    });
});
```

C# (just ignore it):

```
myAwesomium.KeyDown +) KeyyDown;

private void KeyyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  {
    if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
  { 
    #Something 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use `PreviewKeyDown` for that. There you need to set `e.Handled = true`, this will stop processing the keyhandling.

```
private void WebControl1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Hint: You should also set the `ContextMenu` of the `WebControl` to a new `ContextMenu` to prevent printing via the contextmenu entry.

Hope that it help.